# Trying to export a large table from phpmyadmin, only exports 2675 records

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Im trying to copy one table from a MySQL db to another MySQL db, with the exact same structure.

I noticed that when exporting one of the tables, it only exports 2675 records.

I'm using phpmyadmin:
1. Go to Export-tab
2. Select Bzip
3. Run

But this only gives med 1/3 of the original table. What am I missing?

Edit for missing info:
1. phpmyadmin version is 3.3.7deb7
2. Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
3. MySQL client version: 5.1.63

I can't access the db through any other interfaces as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give in more details, which version on phpmyadmin, which OS.

And did you try exporting database by other methods, an alternative is here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707930/mysql-db-import-export-command-line-in-windows

Comment: I just added the extra infomation. I can't access the the db from my terminal (mac) as of know, would it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Windows OS, locate the `my.conf` file in the wamp folder. Change the `max_allowed_packet` value accordingly.